# Symfony: ManyToOne Form Issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities called, Ticket & TicketUpdate.
Each Ticket can have many TicketUpdates, but every TicketUpdate can only have 1 Ticket.

Next I have a form which shows the current Ticket, but also allows me to add 1 TicketUpdate & change attributes of Ticket.

This is my controller:

```
//TicketController.php

...

/**
 * @Route("/ticket/{id}", name="app_ticket")
 */
public function ticket(Request $request, Ticket $ticket)
{
    $ticketUpdate = new TicketUpdate();
    $ticketUpdate->setTicket($ticket);

    $form = $this->createForm(TicketUpdateType::class, $ticketUpdate); //custom form type
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ticketUpdate);
        $em->persist($ticket);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('ticket/view.html.twig', ['ticket' => $ticket, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
}

...
```

TicketUpdateType:

```
//TicketUpdateType.php

...

class TicketUpdateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('text', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'update', 'required' => false, 'attr' => ['class' => 'textarea-sm'])
            ->add('ticket', TicketType::class, ['label' => false, 'by_reference' => false]) //custom Type for Tickets
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'save']);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TicketUpdate::class
        ]);
    }
}

...
```

However, this solution does **not** work for me. Symfony always wants to create a **new** Ticket entry, instead of changing the old one.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: have you tried without the $em->persist($ticket); ? Symfony should automatically handle that when you do $em->persist($ticketUpdate);

Comment: I would assume, your `setTicket` or something related does something weird. Or the Ticket given to the route is not managed. Doctrine wouldn't create a new ticket entry if the entity is already managed.

Comment: Symfony is quite weird is this case. Sometimes it literally does nothing. It just reloads the form with the data I entered and sometimes I get following error:

A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\TicketUpdate#ticket' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\Ticket@000000000b6938470000000073fc59d8. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this ....

When I add cascading, it would also create a **new** entry, instead of changing the old one.

Comment: I am pretty sure, that Ticket is managed. Atleast creating new Ticket objects and also editing works fine (also with forms).
Maybe the issue is my TicketUpdateType ? I'll add it to my question, maybe someone can spot a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I changed by_reference to **true** and removed every logic in my TicketType, which seemed to cause the issue.

Atleast for now I got it running. Here is my controller:

```
//TicketController.php

...

/**
 * @Route("/ticket/{id}", name="app_ticket")
 */
public function ticket(Request $request, Ticket $ticket)
{
    $ticketUpdate = new TicketUpdate();
    $ticketUpdate->setTicket($ticket);

    $form = $this->createForm(TicketUpdateType::class, $ticketUpdate); //custom form type
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ticketUpdate);
        //$em->persist($ticket); -> removed, will be automatically updated by symfony
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('ticket/view.html.twig', ['ticket' => $ticket, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

May you know, a magic with symfony forms, with you can get an Entity (Ticket), like in your example, I dont know... but this will working:

```
/**
* @Route("/ticket/{ticketId}", name="app_ticket", requirements={"ticketId"="\d+"})
*/
public function ticket(Request $request, int $ticketId = 0)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $ticket = $em->getRepository(Ticket::class)
    ->findOneBy([
        'id' => $ticketId
    ]);

    if ($ticket instanceof Ticket === false)
    {
        die('Ticket dont exist with the requested ID.'); #Just return here some error message
    }

    $ticketUpdate = new TicketUpdate();

    //Because your setTicket() setter inside your TicketUpdate Entity
    //sure have nullable typehinted argument (?Ticket $ticket)
    //if this is a valid doctrine relationship
    //(but if i'm wrong, please show the touched parts of your TicketUpdate entity)
    $ticketUpdate->setTicket($ticket); #<-- here is an "old" Ticket $ticket

    $form = $this->createForm(TicketUpdateType::class, $ticketUpdate); //custom form type
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $em->persist($ticketUpdate);

        //I'm working a lot with doctrine relationships
        //In many time necessary using a setter in the both Entity
        $ticket->addTicketUpdate($ticketUpdate); #You know this setter! Change, if my tip wrong
        $em->persist($ticket);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('ticket/view.html.twig', [
        //Now, this is an instance of the Ticket
        //not an int ID!
        //so if you need the ID, you can get in twig, like:
        //{{ ticket.id }}
        'ticket' => $ticket, #Or: $ticket->getId()
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

The requirements inside the @route means, the method will running only on pages, where the {ticketId} is numeric.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer. Sadly this does not work for me. The Ticket Entity will not be saved. Another thing I noticed, is that my form **sometimes** seems to fail the if-part (form valid & submitted). This is really confusing, since I have no idea what symfony does in the background.